# can not convert CGPoint to expected argument to expected argument CGFloat

Tags: swift

this is the line of code where the error is shown

```
let moveEnemy = SKAction.moveTo(x: endPoint, duration: 1.5)
```

heres everything invloving it

```
let startPoint = CGPoint(x: randomXStart, y: self.size.height * 1.2)
let endPoint = CGPoint(x: radnomXEnd, y: -self.size.height * 0.2)
    
let enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemy")
enemy.setScale(1)
enemy.position = startPoint
enemy.zPosition = 2
self.addChild(enemy)
    
let moveEnemy = SKAction.moveTo(x: endPoint, duration: 1.5)
let deleteEnemy = SKAction.removeFromParent()
let enemySequence = SKAction.sequence([moveEnemy, deleteEnemy])
enemy.runAction(enemySequence)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear: `endPoint` is `CGPoint` and the first parameter of `moveTo(x:duration:)` is `CGFloat`

Either use the *point* API

```
let moveEnemy = SKAction.move(to: endPoint, duration: 1.5)
```

or get the `x` portion of the point

```
let moveEnemy = SKAction.moveTo(x: endPoint.x, duration: 1.5)
```